# ASP.net MVC 4 global Authorize filter forcing login on an AllowAnonymous action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

In my .NET MVC 4 I'm adding a global filter in order to secure my controllers.
This is done using:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
   filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
   filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Which is invoked from my Global.cs class.

My Web.config file contains a standard configuration:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

My Login action is decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]` in order to allow anonymous users to login.

So far so good, everything works great. Here is my Login action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Now, I wanted to add a reset-password page which also just like the login page should be available to anonymous users. I created me action (under the same controller of the Login action) and decorated it with the `[AllowAnonymous]` decoration:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPasswordForUser(string message = "")
{
    ViewBag.message = message;
    return View();
}
```

Then created the corresponding view.

I added this link to my Login page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ResetPasswordForUser", "Account")
```

In runtime, as I click this link using an anonymous user I do get to the ResetPasswordForUser action, but when returning the view the Login action gets invoked and I can never actually get to the desired view. For some reason my request gets intercepted even though I'm using the [AllowAnonymous] decoration.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

**Update1:**

As per Darin Dimitrov request adding my ResetPasswordForUser view:

```
@using TBS.Models
@model TBS.ViewModels.ResetPasswordForUserViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset Password";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table class="edit-table rounded bordered" style="width: 400px">
        <tr>
            <td class="label-td">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label-td">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Password("Password")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="submit" value="Reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Is there an <authorization> section in config?  If so, that could interfere with MVC's authorization mechanisms.

Comment: My Web.config file contains <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="720" />
</authentication>

Comment: You pasted the <authentication> section, not the <authorization> section.  It is the latter that can cause problems.  Also, make sure you're using System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymousAttribute instead of the one from the System.Web.Http namespace.

Comment: @Levi I do not have an <authorization> section in my Web.config and my  AllowAnonymousAttribute is indeed under System.Web.Mvc as you can see here: http://pbrd.co/XUnm6H  (while hovering over the ResetPasswordForUser method decoration)

Comment: Could you show your `ResetPasswordForUser.cshtml` view?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Sure, I have updated the question with the view. Thanks.

Comment: What's the URL in browser after switch to Login happens?

Comment: @Nenad Once clicking the reset password link the browser redirects to login page with url: http://localhost:53762/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fResetPasswordForUser

Comment: And, if I understand well, you can hit break point in ResetPasswordForUser action? Then after continuing it redirects to above URL?

Comment: @Nenad Yes, you are correct. Right after returning the View from the ResetPasswordForUser action I hit the Login action brakepoint (and this is the whole enigma actually), then as expected the Login view is returned

Comment: I've tried recreating your issue in a MVC 4 internet application and following what you've done up the top, it works for me.  IF you try the same do you produce the same problem?  Do you mind posting your project code somewhere and I'll have a look......  it would be an excuse not to do the dishes.... I hate dishes!!

Comment: Is it possible that the _Layout file used by the `ResetPasswordForUser` view is invoking an Action in your Controller (e.g. in a menu?) that hasn't been decorated with `AllowAnonymous`? This would cause this type of behaviour.

Comment: A colleague of mine wrote very silimar functionality - his blog post here may help http://andyck1.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/securing-your-mvc-intranet-applications.html also he released it via nuget so you could also poke about with that too http://nuget.org/packages/ValidationAndAuthenticationByDefault.MVC3/

Comment: Do you have any code in Application_BeginRequest - perhaps some custom authentication code that could be responsible??

Comment: I do have my own custom membership provider, but i did not change any code in Application_BeginRequest.

Comment: Do you need the @using TBS.Models ? Try it again without this using in your view - I have no other idea at the moment ;)

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler2 http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to analyse the traffic and see what is causing the redirect?

Comment: Are you able to set a break-point in your view?

Comment: As someone already said here you need to use Fiddler to see what requests are being made and when. Once you have that then you can go through your code and see what is redirecting you to Login View since it seems that you are hitting the action correctly but you're not rendering the proper view...

Do you have a BaseController maybe? Does your base controller perform some sort of redirect? Are you doing something in global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest or PostAuthenticateRequest? It's hard to answer without seeing your entire code...

Comment: Perhaps your view is erroring or something like that.  As @ChristopherHarris said, try putting a breakpoint in there and see if you get any exceptions.

Comment: The View() method (or another filter) is most likely returning a 403, which is what IIS will intercept to generate a redirect to the login page. Can you reproduce in an empty project?

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was wrong. What is the url when you go to /Controller/Login? Does it have returnUrl attached to the end?

Comment: Does any part of your _Layout have Html.Action or Html.RenderAction in it?

Comment: @DanVanWinkle Sorry, was away for a while. Thank you for not giving up on me :)  I went over my layout files (got quite a few) and yes - one of those files invokes Html.Action. This actions is not decorated with the [AllowAnonymous] decoration and I'm quite sure this is what causing the issue. It will take me a few days to test it since I have a few other blocking bugs prior this one. I will let you know of my progress, might ask you to post it as an answer. Many thanks!!!

Comment: I went ahead and modified my previous answer, but, while I didn't see it until just now, @AlistairFindlay was the first to suggest this. If he makes an answer, you should accept his instead of mine.

Comment: Thanks @DanVanWinkle - I've went ahead and created an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it possible that the _Layout file used by the `ResetPasswordForUser` view is invoking an Action in your Controller (e.g. in a menu?) that hasn't been decorated with `AllowAnonymous`?

This would cause this type of behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you could have a non-anonymous @Html.Action or Html.RenderAction in your layout, which is causing your page to redirect to login.

Edit: Deleted old answer as it was incorrect and not useful for anyone coming to see it.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I'm also surprised that I got no answers. I based my solution over: http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-allowanonymous-attribute-and-authorize-attribute. Did it because I wanted to save the need to add the [Authorize] decoration to each of my controllers, I think this is pretty basic. According to that you say I must have this decoration for each of my controllers (assuming they all require authorized users)? It might work, but sure sounds like an overhead to me.

Comment: Well, there is a work around to that as well, Create your own base controller and add the attribute to that. Of course, you still have to add : BaseController to each controller, but having your own base controller is good practice anyway.

Comment: Okay, I have been playing around with this more, and my answer may be wrong. One question, when you go to login, does the url have a returnUrl in it, or is it just /Controller/Login?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if adding that global authorize filter conflicts with AllowAnonymous. The way I set up my project is to have a Base Controller that has the [Authorize] attribute set at the controller level.

All my controllers inherit from this BaseController except for ones that require anonymous access, usually my AccountController and my MarketingController. Those simply inherit from Controller and then I can set [Authorize] at the Action level.